# Does web safe fonts needs to be purchased license for usage on a commercial website?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to use Helvitica font for a client, and I thought we need to purchase the font to be used on the website to have a valid license for commercial work, but I found in this article: https://websitesetup.org/web-safe-fonts-html-css/ that Helvetica is a web safe font and all devices have it already. So do we need to still purchase the Webfont to legally use it on a website?

Comment: https://www.fonts.com/font/linotype/helvetica/licenses

Comment: Helvetica has very poor coverage: Windows: 7.34%. https://www.cssfontstack.com/Helvetica . It is definitely not a websafe font.

Answer (score 0):

The point of web safe fonts is that they are likely to be available on a significant number of client computers already.

Since you aren't distributing it, you don't need a license for it.

Comment: I thought you had to have a server license if you wanted to use helvetica font on your website

Comment: @Pete If you were loading a font using [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) then you would need a licence. Using `font-family: Helvetica;` wouldn't since you aren't distributing the font files.

Comment: @Turnip Ah I guess I've always gone the font-face route as it isn't well supported on windows machines which is why we've usually needed a license